What is the proper way to use the local storage PV in AKS on a storage optimized Windows node?
I am investigating the local storage option. It seems to require an existing directory on the node where the volume is created. In my case these are Windows nodes.
And that raises the question - what is the proper way to do it?
Using these instructions I was able to inspect the file system on the windows nodes and create a directory of my choice. By arranging it as a DaemonSet I can ensure this directory will be created on any new Windows nodes. However, I am not sure if this is the proper way to enable the local storage.
Also, the VMs in the Windows nodepool are storage optimized (Standard_L8s_v3) but I have no idea how to take advantage of it.
EDIT 1
The solution I concocted so far can be found in this GitHub repo - https://github.com/MarkKharitonov/test-aks-win-local-storage. (If you want to try it yourself be sure to edit the node tolerations and labels)
